# Call swift func in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, function, swift

I use obj c in my swift project and it work (with bridge file). 
But if I want call a swift function by "example.m" file how I can do that? Like:

**EDIT:**
I use Swift like first language

```
- (void)start
{
    var i=0;
    if( i == 0)
    {
        //How I can call a swift function? 
    }
}
```

Comment: Just call it. What's the problem? Is it that your Objective-C code doesn't see your Swift code? Describe the _actual_ situation in detail. Don't just wave your hands around.

Comment: I don't think you have to do anything special. Just call it like you would any swift function. If that doesn't work, post your updated code with the call to the function

Answer (score 2):

***Used following steps to call swift function from objective-c class***

STEP 1 :  Add #import "YourProjectNameSwift-Swift.h" in "YourObjectiveClass.m"

```
#import "YourProjectNameSwift-Swift.h"
```

STEP 2 : Add @class YourSwiftClass in YourObjectiveClass.h;
Ex:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class YourSwiftClassViewController;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
```

STEP 3 :  Then in YourObjectiveClass.m

```
`YourSwiftClassViewController *myClassInstance = [YourSwiftClassViewController new];`

 [myClassInstance swiftClassMethodName];
```

{Call Like it in any method whether you want to call swift method.}

STEP 4 :  you need to put @objc before Swift Class

```
@objc class YourSwiftClass: UIViewController {

    let sliceAngle = ((M_PI * 2) / 8)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    //MARK:- Instance Methods

    func spinLayer(inLayer: CALayer, duration: CFTimeInterval, direction: Int, index: Int, mImageView: UIImageView) {
        // Rotate about the z axis
        CATransaction.begin()

        let rotationAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")

    }

}
```

> NOTE :-  If you inherit from an Objective-C class like NSObject then you
>   don't need to put @objc before Class Name.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that you put `@objc`  before your swift class. If you want to use a swift class in your objective-c code you always need `@objc` before `class`

```
@objc class foo{
    func printSomething() {
        println("Hello World")
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you inherit from an Objective-C class like `NSObject` you don't need to put `@objc` before it.
Thanks to @Logan

Comment: And what I have to write in start function ? (in obj c code)

Comment: Not always, only for classes that don't inherit from an ObjC class like NSObject.

Comment: @Annachiara take a look at this link: http://ericasadun.com/2014/08/21/swift-calling-swift-functions-from-objective-c/ If you searched at google for: call swift function in objective-c code you would come up with different solutions. So before you ask a question do some research!